# Delete an entire index with SolrJ

Tags: java, search, indexing, solr, solrj

I'm using SolrJ to index articles on my site. Periodically, I'm going to want to clear the whole index and do a fresh re-index of all articles.

The ID of each entry is tied to the ID of the article (something to the effect of [blog ID]-[article ID]). I know that SolrJ has a deleteById() method, but if an article is removed from my site, I may lose access to its ID on the Java side, so I can't reliably iterate over all articles and call deleteById(). Is there any way to drop an entire index using SolrJ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
server.deleteByQuery( "*:*" );
```

Then

```
server.commit()
```

You should first delete by query, do a full index, and then commit, so that the old index remains until the new one is committed.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much! I appreciate the advice about committing as well, didn't realize you could use it that way.